# How to execute a perl script within php and capture error messages?

Tags: php, perl, die

I am trying to execute a Perl script like so:

```
/usr/bin/ec2-consistent-snapshot 'vol-dr3131c2'
```

When the Perl script fails it exits using 'die' and prints out an error message. I can see that error message when executing manually, but I am failing to capture it through PHP.

I tried the following with no success:

```
exec($command,$output);
echo system($command,$output);
passthru($command);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
$command = "/usr/bin/ec2-consistent-snapshot 'vol-dr3131c2' > /tmp/exec.out 2>&1"
exec($command)
echo file_get_contents('/tmp/exec.out');
```

The '> /tmp/exec.out 2>&1' redirects all output to /tmp/exec.out, then PHP echo's the file back.

Comment: Will try that out. Any idea why PHP can't capture the output? I have a feeling that the error message is not going to stdout.

Comment: The error messages are probably going to stderr and PHP is only receiving stdout. I just threw that code up there quickly without thinking about it differently, but you could probably remove the '> /tmp/exec.out' section and just have it redirect stderr to stdout '2>&1'. If that works, you won't be left w/ a tmp file and PHP /SHOULD/ capture the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't PHP have backticks?

```
$output = `$command 2> /tmp/command.err`;
if (looks_like_command_failed($output)) {
    $error_message = file_get_contents('/tmp/command.err');
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. 
In fact, it has very poor facilities for running other programs (and a significant bug in 5.2: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44994)

Comment: It turns out that on my planet, PHP does have backticks: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=PHP+backticks .

Answer (score 0):

The first example given in the documentation for the [system()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function mentions that it may work in cases where output is not being received by php.  The example receives stderr separately from stdout, without using a temp file.  The poster doesn't explain why this method would be successful when system() is not.  So no answer to the root issue, but maybe a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Perl scripts die with their messages going to stderr, so you will need to capture stderr as well as stdout to see what happened.